# Add text below specific lines in text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, text

I want to add output text into spesific line of text.

I have a dataframe like below :

| text | similarity | polarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDD | 0.6 | POSITIF |
| ASDAS | 0.4 | NEGATIF |
| ASGAS | 1.0 | POSITIF |

I have a function that can print text based on if function, here's the code :

```
with open("testttttt.txt","a") as myfile:
    for key, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['Similarity'] > 0.5) and ('POSITIF' in row['polarity']): 
            myfile.writelines('untitled-ontology-5:membangun untitled-ontology-5:positif ;\n')
```

But, the output will be added into the last line of the file.Like this:

[image]

I want to add the output into specific line of the text file.
For this case, I want to add the output into the text above line 119
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide some more information about your data. I'd rather go with:

```
with open("testttttt.txt","r+") as myfile:
    content = myfile.read().split("\n")
    i = 0
    for key, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['Similarity'] > 0.5) and ('POSITIF' in row['polarity']): 
            content.insert(i, 'untitled-ontology-5:membangun untitled-ontology-5:positif ;')
            i += 1
        i += 1
    myfile.seek(0)
    myfile.write("\n".join(content))
    myfile.truncate()
```